# make a One to Many Relation in django

Tags: django, database-design, one-to-many

I am trying to make a one-to-many relation in django.

In my model I have a class Person and a class Group and the relation I want to make is that one Group can have N people inside, and a group cann't exist without at least one person inside

In a MER diagram it would be like(imagine these are entities and relations)

|group|1====<>-----N|person|

Comment: You should note that the tag [mer] refers to the Mer project (mobile Linux distribution). Therefore I've removed that tag from your question.

Comment: oh, thanks for the advice. I didnt know that there was a linux distro called mer XD

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Arthur states, this is documented quite well in the Django documentation.

It is in fact quite easy:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    # Some other fields
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='people')

class Group(models.Model):
    # Some fields
```

As you can see, you simply create a foreign key in the person class -> this is quite equivalent to how you would set it up manually in the database, if you should do so.

Django will automatically add the reverse relation, such that you can find people from a group:

```
some_group.people
```

Note that the `related_name` specifies the name of the reverse relation. This is optional, but I guess you want to use `people` instead of `persons`.

Comment: Yes but no :P Is not exactly what i need. I need that group know person, not the oposite.

Comment: If you add the foreign key field as described, Django will automatically add the reverse relation, such that you can query `some_group.persons`. If you want to use `some_group.people`, you can set the related name to "people". I edited the post to reflect this.