# Correct way to assign unique group to users Django

Tags: django, architecture

I read about it on the next articles, trying to find information about my doubt:

https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/group-combo-box-django-user-profile-form/

https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-permissions-and-groups/

https://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangousers.html

My premise in my system: an user only can be in an unique group.

My question is about my premise, how is the correct way to assign a unique group to an user from my app?

Comment: It's easy to do, but what's the point? Groups have one goal: put several users together.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur comment. I have multiple groups in my app: teachers, class room leaders, coordinator, etc. An user can be only in one group no multiple groups. I don't know how can do it: I must to use "auth_user_groups" table for unique relationship? or maybe i must to build a custom table "profile" and create a FK group table relation? What option is better?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. It got lost in translation.

Comment: Excuse my english :(

Comment: No problem. When you say "each user must have a unique group" it reads as "each user must have it's own group, with no other users in it".

Comment: No really. I mean, one group can have many users but an user can only belong to one group. It is a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Groups are added to AbstractUser via PermissionsMixin and is a ManyToManyField. There's two ways to do this:

1. You listen to [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed) for the User model and then implement some logic to deny multiple groups.
2. You [create your own user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) with a `ForeignKey` to `Group` on your new `ProjectUser` model and reimplement PermissionsMixin and AbstractUser.

The first method is a little tricky and I don't recommend it. The second has the disadvantage that you can pretty much copy 80% of PermissionsMixin and everything, but it's inheritance from AbstractUser, but have to keep it in sync with new releases. It's a shame Django implemented it this way to be honest.

But the upside to the second is that the relation between User and Group is now as you define it in your requirements. So for me, keeping a correct Data Model instead of hacking around it, wins.

Take a look at `django.contrib.auth.models` for the classes I mentioned.

To clarify the second method:

`app/models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, Group

class ProjectUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    # fields and methods from AbstractUser go here
    # fields and methods from PermissionsMixin go here
```

(Sorry, it's two classes instead of one you need to copy).

Comment: Thanks for ur answer @Melvyn. About the second option, you mean, i must to build all user logic (login, register, session) and forget Django User Auth? I was reading about my doubt and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997562/make-a-one-to-many-relation-in-django What do u think about it?

Comment: No, you only need to reimplement [PermissionMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L203). That answer you linked works, but then you really have to reimplement everything with respect to authentication and permissions.

Comment: About ur suggestion, i must to rewrite Class PermissionsMixin in my project? or what do u mean about to "reimplement PermissionMisin" feature? Thanks!